# 1054, "Unknown column 'user_account_id_fk_id' in 'field list'"

Tags: python, django, django-models

I focusing in insert log table that relate with user account and i have got a problem about inserting new row using django in views file. So it may came from my models. I Have no idea how to fixed this problem.

I was change both of models settings and in views file by change queryset using get all and filter

Models file

```py
class user_account(models.Model):
    user_account_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=11, unique=True, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    display_name =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email =  models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_delete = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=1)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()
    create_user_account_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=11)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField()
    modify_user_account_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=11)
    delete_date = models.DateTimeField()
    delete_user_account_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=11)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField()
    is_authenticated = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=1)


    class Meta:
        app_label = 'users'
        db_table = 'user_account'

class user_account_log(models.Model):
    user_account_log_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    user_account_id_fk = models.ForeignKey(user_account, unique=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name = 'user_acc')
    action = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    refer_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    refer_table = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'users'
        db_table = 'user_account_log'
```

Views file

```py
user_log = user_account_log()

user_log.action = "aaaa"
user_log.title = ""
user_log.description =""
user_log.refer_id = "AAAA"
user_log.refer_table = ""

user_log.user_account_id_fk_id = str(user_account.objects.get(user_account_id=request.user.user_account_id).user_account_id)


# Save
user_log.save()
```

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:2499/user/users_list/test42/delete/

Django Version: 2.2.1
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'dashboard_app',
 'user_app',
 'django_mysql']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py" in execute
  71.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in execute
  206.         res = self._query(query)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in _query
  312.         db.query(q)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py" in query
  224.         _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

The above exception ((1054, "Unknown column 'user_account_id_fk_id' in 'field list'")) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\SwappingBatteryWepApp\user_app\views.py" in user_change
  298.                 user_log.save()

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  908.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1186.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1335.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py" in execute
  71.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in execute
  206.         res = self._query(query)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in _query
  312.         db.query(q)

File "C:\Users\chalothorn_c\.conda\envs\Analytics\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py" in query
  224.         _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /user/users_list/test42/delete/
Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'user_account_id_fk_id' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: typo `user_log.user_account_id_fk_id ` --> `user_log.user_account_id_fk `

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @Rakesh I have done this. But it still raise error  this "Cannot assign "'8'": "user_account_log.user_account_id_fk" must be a "user_account" instance."

Comment: @Alasdair i was updated traceback.

Comment: It looks as if you need to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after adding the field to the model.

Comment: @Alasdair Already migrate and problem was solved, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:  Insert parameter name "**db_column**" in model.

Example:

> user_account_id_fk = models.ForeignKey(user_account, unique=True, >db_column='user_account_id_fk', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)